# Communicate exe to web page

Tags: c#, exe

I have created a tool which user downloads and it gathers some information from users system . I need to show that information on a webpage . I can insert it to database from exe by calling a webservice . Is there any way other than that to push that information to webpage from exe ? I have to store information to database in this case . Is there any other approach ?

Comment: [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Comment: A webservice is really ideal for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way other than that to push that information to webpage
>   from exe ?

Yes and No. Yes, because you can create a socket connection, for example, and stream the data. No because the web service is the best approach.